# Neo4j assembly error when running through Revit software

Tags: c#, neo4j, .net-assembly, revit-api

I am building an addin for Autodesk's Revit.
I created a class library .NET Framework project called `neo4jTest`.

I'm trying to use the Neo4j API to communicate with the DB and save data to it.

I try to following:

1. Compile the .dll, and place the .dll file and .addin file in the
   Revit folder which can load it.
2. Start Revit, and click "Load Once" for the addin approval.
3. Click the **Button** I've created (in the appropriate Tab)
4. Error appears (image below)
5. Run the `.dll` directly from the `add-in manager` -> no error.
6. Click the **Button** again -> no error.

[image]

I am expecting:

1. No error, and that both the direct execution of the `.dll`, and the **Button**, to perform the same action.
2. Neo4j DB logs the data being sent. Currently I can't see the data is actually being updated.

Is Revit first loading the assembly locally or caching it in some way when I run the `.dll` directly and then the loaded addin can use it because it is available?

Would appreciate any advice on how to go around this or solve it.
Thank you

**CODE:**

**Main.cs file for button creation:**

```
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System.Reflection;

namespace neo4jTest
{
    public partial class Main : IExternalApplication
    {
        public UIControlledApplication _application;
        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            _application = application;
            string tabName = "Neo4jTest";
            application.CreateRibbonTab(tabName);
            RibbonPanel ribbonPanel = application.CreateRibbonPanel(tabName, "Neo4jTest");
            string thisAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            InitializeButtons(ribbonPanel, thisAssemblyPath);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        private void InitializeButtons(RibbonPanel ribbonPanel, string thisAssemblyPath)
        {
            CreateButton(ribbonPanel, "neo4jTest", "neo4jTest", thisAssemblyPath, "neo4jTest.Class1", "neo4jTest");
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        private void CreateButton(
            RibbonPanel ribbonPanel,
            string name,
            string text,
            string thisAssemblyPath,
            string className,
            string toolTip
            )
        {
            PushButtonData buttonData = new PushButtonData(name, text, thisAssemblyPath, className);
            PushButton pushButton = ribbonPanel.AddItem(buttonData) as PushButton;
            pushButton.ToolTip = toolTip;
        }
    }
}
```

**Neo4jConnection.cs for establishing DB data:**

```
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Neo4j.Driver;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace neo4jTest
{
    public static class Neo4jConnection
    {
        public static IDriver _driver;

        private static readonly string uri = "myUri";
        private static readonly string user = "myUser";
        private static readonly string password = "myPassword";

        public static void SaveToDB()
        {
            try
            {
                _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
                var session = _driver.AsyncSession();

                var data = session.ExecuteWriteAsync(async tx =>
                {
                    var result = await tx.RunAsync("CREATE (n:Testing) " +
                        "SET n.fulltext = testing text " +
                        "SET n.username = userTest " +
                        "RETURN n"
                    );

                    return await result.ToListAsync();
                });

                Thread.Sleep(500);
                session.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("Error", ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Class1 for executing button:**

```
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;

namespace neo4jTest
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Regeneration(RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    public class Class1 : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            Neo4jConnection.SaveToDB();
            TaskDialog.Show("Validate", "Done");

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the steps you are doing? where is the code?

Comment: @jose_bacoy apologies, please see edited post for extensive details. wdyt?